# Не корректно работает "маска ввода" (по слушателю нажатий) в editText

Tags: android, kotlin

Код и его поведение на скрине. Речь идет конечно не о маске ввода, а о слушателе нажатий.
Вопрос - можно ли этот код **малыми** усилиями переделать так, чтобы точки стирались по backspace по одной , а не только все вместе при выделении?

```
fun FirstFragment.inputTextWatch() {
currentField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        when (currentField.text.length) {
            2 -> currentField.append(".")
            5 -> currentField.append(".")
        }
     }
  })
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Малыми усилиями вряд ли выйдет. Попробуйте готовую библиотеку для этого использовать: https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: Вам нужно просто не добавлять точки когда количество символов уменьшается. Сейчас вы их добавляете всегда, поэтому они и множатся.

Comment: подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб она на jave, и мне не не удалось её вписать в проект, какие-то ошибки...

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. Либа не на джаве

Comment: да немного не точно выразился, с этой библиотекой просто были ошибки в проекте AndroidStudio... Про java имел в виду https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask . Эта библиотека даже лучше - в ней не удаляется hint. Но она на jave и не смог её интегрировать в свой проект.

Comment: Не посмотрите мой обновленный ответ? (про схлопывание строки) может мысли какие-то будут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335323/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-edittext-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Малыми усилиями если что так:

```
currentField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    var isAdded = true

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
      isAdded = count < after
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
      if (isAdded) {
        when (s.length) {
          2 -> s.append(".")
          5 -> s.append(".")
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: спасибо! этот вопрос отвечен, почти идеально, но есть небольшой ньанс - задам новый вопрос

Comment: новый вопрос здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335323/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-edittext-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA