# Не срабатывает "маска" слушателя нажатий в editText при изменении введенного текста

Tags: android, kotlin

Проблема на скриншоте. Использование масок ввода пока не предлагать.
Вместо второй тройки должна ставиться точка. По идее надо вычислять именно количество символов перед курсором...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
fun FirstFragment.inputTextWatch() {
    currentField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        var isAdded = true

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            isAdded = count < after
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            if (isAdded) {
                when (s.length) {
                    2 -> s.append(".")
                    5 -> s.append(".")
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Предполагаю что можно использовать вместо append в этой части кода какую-то другую инструкцию... Например, replace()... Но правильно не могу собрать код, ошибка. Понятно что `S` имеет другой тип....
И вообще нужно со строкой работать как с массивом - что-то вроде

```
val character = s[2]
if (character != ".") s[2] = "."  ....

override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
 isAdded = count < after
  when (s.length) {
        when (s.length) {
            3 -> s.replaceRange(3, 3, ".")
            6 -> s.replaceRange(6, 6, ".")
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не корректно работает "маска ввода" (по слушателю нажатий) в editText](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1334943/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-edittext)

Comment: вопрос в той теме касался проблемы что точки не стираются, и он отвечен. Это совершенно новая проблема. - нужно заменять третий и шестой символ на точку или просто не давать ставить дальше символы, а перескакивать на четвертую и седьмую позицию. С учетом предложенного в том вопросе решения

Comment: 34 отличный номер месяца, наверное будет следующий вопрос про месяцы и годы и потом отдельный про 31 февраля. У вас XY проблема. Вызывайте DatePicker и не морочьте себе голову, если нужен ручной ввод, то ищите библиотеки. Вы тратите время впустую.

Comment: Специфика состоит в том, что datapicker не подходит, нужен ручной ввод, а на проверку введенной даты у меня стоит функция.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov эти проверки у меня уже стоят на выходе из поля. Сейчас идет речь только о как бы "маске ввода"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение "в лоб". Больше за вас писать код не буду :)
Работа со строками - одна из основ программирования.

```
currentField.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        var str = s.toString().replace(".", "")
        if (str.length > 2) {
            str = "${str.take(2)}.${str.drop(2)}"
        }
        if (str.length > 5) {
            str = "${str.take(5)}.${str.drop(5)}"
        }
        if (str != s.toString()) {
            s.replace(0, s.length, str)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: спасибо, я честно пытался разобрать строку как массив и при условии что строка достигает длины 3 или 6 символов - подставлять между 2 и 3 или 5 и 6 символом точку.... даже код стал собирать ) ` var slovo = "123" `  `if (slovo.length == 3) {`
        `val chars = slovo.toMutableList()`
        `chars[2] = if (chars[2].equals("3".single())) ".".single() else "".single()`
        `println(chars.joinToString(separator = ""))     }`

Comment: появился небольшой нюанс снова - при стирании , например, 4 последних цифр пропадает и точка перед ними. Можно её не стирать а оставлять для наглядности? Скриншот https://pickasso.info/images/2021/10/06/0b7c932e3cf6997959c3ff3153717ac6.gif

Comment: Можно все, комбинируйте первое решение с идентификацией удаления и это.

Comment: так и сделал ) вроде всё как нужно! спасибо